# How to sort files according to my pattern

Tags: r, csv

I'm using `fs::dir_ls(path, regexp = paste0("LATO-", "[[:alpha:]]*", ".csv$"))` to get a list of files in a specific directory.

The files are, by default, sorted alphabetically. Is there any way in R to keep them sorted according to my pattern

LATO-sty.csv, LATO-lut.csv, LATO-mar.csv, LATO-kwi.csv, LATO-maj.csv, LATO-cze.csv, LATO-lip.csv
LATO-sie.csv, LATO-wrz.csv, LATO-paz.csv, LATO-lis.csv, LATO-gru.csv

Comment: I don't understand. If you already have the list of file (i.e. LATO-sty.csv, LATO-lut.csv, LATO-mar.csv, ...), why do you need `dir_ls` ?

Comment: Sidenote: your regex `paste0("LATO-", "[[:alpha:]]*", ".csv$")` can be simplified to `"LATO-[[:alpha:]]*.csv$"`. And at the `.` should be escaped: `"LATO-[[:alpha:]]*\\.csv$"`

Comment: In the regular expression I also use an additional variable "year". Is it possible to simplify this expression somehow, or must paste0 () remain

`rok<- 2022
csv_files <- fs::dir_ls(path, regexp = paste0("LATO-", "[[:alpha:]]*", "-", rok, ".csv$"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're describing is not a generic pattern we can apply to all possible values in your file listing. However, we can make sure that *if* these specific values appear in your vector, they get sorted to the front:

Example `fs::dir_ls()` data:

```r
files <- c('some/dir/LATO-bar.csv', 'some/dir/LATO-baz.csv', 'some/dir/LATO-foo.csv',
           'some/dir/LATO-kwi.csv', 'some/dir/LATO-lut.csv', 'some/dir/LATO-sty.csv',
           'some/dir/ZLATO-bar.csv', 'some/dir/ZLATO-baz.csv')
```

Code:

```r
order <- c('LATO-sty.csv', 'LATO-lut.csv', 'LATO-mar.csv', 'LATO-kwi.csv',
           'LATO-maj.csv', 'LATO-cze.csv', 'LATO-lip.csv', 'LATO-sie.csv',
           'LATO-wrz.csv', 'LATO-paz.csv', 'LATO-lis.csv', 'LATO-gru.csv')


# get `files` present in `order`
set1 <- files[fs::path_file(files) %in% order] # extract filenames
ids <- match(fs::path_file(set1), order)       # get matching IDs from `order`
ids_sorted <- sort(ids, index.return=T)        # get sort order
set1_sorted <- set1[ids_sorted$ix]             # apply sort order

# get `files` NOT present in `order`, keep them in the same order
set2 <- files[!fs::path_file(files) %in% order]

# join sets
result <- unname(c(set1_sorted, set2))
```

Result:

```r
> result
[1] "some/dir/LATO-sty.csv"  "some/dir/LATO-lut.csv"  "some/dir/LATO-kwi.csv"  "some/dir/LATO-bar.csv"  "some/dir/LATO-baz.csv" 
[6] "some/dir/LATO-foo.csv"  "some/dir/ZLATO-bar.csv" "some/dir/ZLATO-baz.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have this alphabetically sorted names,

```
x
# [1] "LATO-cze.csv" "LATO-gru.csv" "LATO-kwi.csv" "LATO-lip.csv" "LATO-lis.csv" "LATO-lut.csv"
# [7] "LATO-maj.csv" "LATO-mar.csv" "LATO-paz.csv" "LATO-sie.csv" "LATO-sty.csv" "LATO-wrz.csv"
```

you may easily sort them according to a minimal pattern

```
pattern <- c("sty", "lut", "mar", "kwi", "maj", "cze", "lip", "sie", "wrz", "paz", 
             "lis", "gru")
```

or if you want to type the whole pattern and think it is safer in your case,

```
pattern <- c("LATO-sty.csv", "LATO-lut.csv", "LATO-mar.csv", ...)
```

using `grep`.

```
sapply(pattern, grep, x)
# sty lut mar kwi maj cze lip sie wrz paz lis gru 
#  11   6   8   3   7   1   4  10  12   9   5   2 

sapply(pattern, grep, x, value=TRUE)  ## use `value=TRUE` to check if it's right
# sty            lut            mar            kwi            maj            cze 
# "LATO-sty.csv" "LATO-lut.csv" "LATO-mar.csv" "LATO-kwi.csv" "LATO-maj.csv" "LATO-cze.csv" 
# lip            sie            wrz            paz            lis            gru 
# "LATO-lip.csv" "LATO-sie.csv" "LATO-wrz.csv" "LATO-paz.csv" "LATO-lis.csv" "LATO-gru.csv"
```

To finally sort the list `lst`, we simply subset it with `grep` result.

```
lst[sapply(pattern, grep, x)]
# $`LATO-sty.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-lut.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-mar.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-kwi.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-maj.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-cze.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-lip.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-sie.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-wrz.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-paz.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-lis.csv`
# list()
# 
# $`LATO-gru.csv`
# list()
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c("LATO-cze.csv", "LATO-gru.csv", "LATO-kwi.csv", "LATO-lip.csv", 
"LATO-lis.csv", "LATO-lut.csv", "LATO-maj.csv", "LATO-mar.csv", 
"LATO-paz.csv", "LATO-sie.csv", "LATO-sty.csv", "LATO-wrz.csv"
)

lst <- setNames(replicate(12, list()), x)
```

Comment: You're assuming that `x` contains all patterns, and that all files will match a pattern correctly. In that case, you can also just do `paste0("LATO-",pattern,".csv")`. Consider cases where not all files are present or for instance the files `"LATO-lip.csv", "LATO-lips.csv"` both exist.

Comment: @CasparV. `grep` would also work with `pattern <- c("st", "lu", "ma", "kw", "cz", "li", "si", "wr", "pa", "gr")` where `paste` fails. In `grep` we're actually using a regex whereas in `paste` it's hard-coded, that's the main difference.

Comment: @CasparV. To prevent more than three characters we can include the period after three characters,  `paste0(pattern, '\\.')` (needs to be escaped in regex).

Comment: Then it'd still match `"LATO-slip.csv"`. You could add a `-` in front, but it'd match `LATO-s-lip.csv`. And still it requires that all regexes match 1 file, no more no less.